# Visual Studio/ Visual Studio Code C# Intelisense not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I recently wanted to program in C# for Unity, but the problem is that the offical C# extension from Microsoft dosen't work for me in a script created with Unity, with the new txt trough Windows nor through VS Code directly. I am currently on a mashine that is running Windows 11.

**I tried:**

- Rebooting the PC
- Reinstalling the Extension
- Reinstalling Visual Studio Code
- Trying out Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code Insiders
- Trying to install the .NET frameworks

I just want to use the intelisense, syntax highlighting and so on that come with the normal C# VS Code extension.